# How to get roledefid along with sharepoint groups data using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, modern-experience, groups, sharepoint-permissions

We have a Permissions groups of around 4k in our site collection. In the same site I have created a sub site and given the permissions up to 2k groups. Now when I try to get the groups data in the sub site I am getting all the 4K groups as they were in site collection level. I tried to filter them with permission level as we roledefid to know the permission of the group. But here when I try to get all the groups I am not getting roledefid property in the object.
Is there any query to get roledefid to all the groups.

Code I used to get the groups:

```
    url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    async: async,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: OnError
});
```

Result i am getting with properties:

```
AllowMembersEditMembership: true
AllowRequestToJoinLeave: false
AutoAcceptRequestToJoinLeave: false
Description: ""
Id: 1977
IsHiddenInUI: false
LoginName: "GroupName"
OnlyAllowMembersViewMembership: false
Owner: {__deferred: {…}}
OwnerTitle: "GroupName"
PrincipalType: 8
RequestToJoinLeaveEmailSetting: null
Title: "GroupName"
Users: {__deferred: {…}}
__metadata: {id: "url", uri: "url", type: "SP.Group"}
__proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to get this from the Site Group object alone. Your rest-call only retrieves group information (title, id, description and other metadata).

To retrieve permission levels you will need to do a couple of more calls. See [Users, groups, and roles REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx) to read more about **RoleAssignment** and **RoleDefinition**.

Comment: Should summarize how to get the `roledefid` and do a permission call *here*, in your post, instead of just linking to the answer. If that link were to move, this answer becomes nearly useless. Also, under *RoleAssignment* it only provides how to use `roledefid` to add or remove a role, not to get the `roledefid`. Using the *RoleDefinitionCollection* and getting it by the role's name would be the way to go, it appears, in the REST call, from that link: `/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/roledefinitions
    /getbyname('contribute')?@target='<host web url>'"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below api call:

```
/_api/web/roleassignments?$expand=Member/users,RoleDefinitionBindings
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)), you would want to get the Role Definition ID by doing this for your URL:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/roledefinitions
/getbyname('contribute')?@target='<host web url>'";
```

Where you would replace `<host web url>` with your site collection that is hosting that role, perhaps another `_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl`, but that `target` parameter is not required. It would probably equate to changing your `url` to:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('contribute')";  // 'target' is not required and simply provides a redirect page
```

Note that this is a *role*, not a *group*. You assign *roles* to *groups*.

Microsoft supplies a full example function [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-rest-reference/dn531432(v=office.15)), under the **RoleDefinitionCollection** *GetByName* method:

```
executor.executeAsync({
    url: "<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/roledefinitions/getbyname('contribute')?@target='<host web url>'",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
    success: successHandler,
    error: errorHandler
});
```

But your AJAX above should handle it.

It will not say `roledefid`, but simply `id`, and that number there in that property you get returned is what you need.

```
var items = data.d.results;
if (items.length > 0) { 
    for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var id = items[0].id;
    }
}
```

You would assign this role to a group using the **AddRoleAssignment** API and the ID you obtained.

Microsoft's example URL for the AJAX call:

```
"<app web url>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/roleassignments
/addroleassignment(principalid=21, roledefid=1073741827)
?@target='<host web url>'",
```

Which translates to:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=21, roledefid=1073741827)";
```

So you will also need the principal ID, which is the ID of the group you are assigning the role to, for which you would do a call on that group by name with a URL like:

```
url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('content site owners')";
```

Store its ID and use that ID as the `principalid` in the add role assignment call.